# Изменить цвет button, если background для нее задан в виде drawable

Tags: android-sdk

Необходимо сменить цвет кнопки, если параметр `background` для нее уже задан в виде ресурса `drawable`. Сейчас я прибегнул к такому способу: создал еще один похожий `drawable` ресурс, и когда мне надо, сменяю `background` кнопки на него. Но такой способ мне кажется не очень эффективен, так процессору нужно каждый раз кнопку перерисовывать. Собственно вопрос, можно ли процесс смены цвета кнопки упростить?

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема? Вы не сможете поставить цвет, сохранив прежний `drawable`-ресурс в качестве фона, т.к цвет заменяет текущий фон на себя. Просто когда надо поставить цвет на фон кнопки делайте так

```
 button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

А когда хотите поставить обратно ресурс вот так

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnres);
```

Где `R.drawable.btnres` - это ваш ресурс с именем `btnres` в папке `drawable` (или от её производных)